# passing, dynamically created objects, to a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, accordion

I've created a jQuery UI Accordion image loader that dynamically adds or removes panels. Inside each panel is an image input form control and at the end of the document is a function that is supposed to change the img src in the panel to the newly selected image. Unfortunately, I am getting: `cannot read 'files' of undefined`. I understand why its doing this, I just need a way to dynamically add the panels AND be able to update the img src for the panel that loaded the image.

My code, so far, is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- css links -->
    <link href="/Content/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.0/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- /css links -->
    <!-- js files  -->
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <!-- /js files -->
</head>
<body id="myPage" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="60">
    <script lang="en" type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#PrimaryImageAccordion").accordion({
                collapsible: true
            });
        });
    </script>
    <br /><br />
    <button type='button' onclick='btnAddPrimaryImage_Click();' class='btn btn-default'> Add </button>
    <div id="PrimaryImageAccordion">
        <h4 class="PrimaryImageTitle">Primary Image</h4>
        <div>
            <div class="row form-group">
                <label for="ImageSelector" class="control-label col-md-2">Project Image</label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <input type="file" id="ImageSelector" onchange="ImageSelector_Change(this);" /><br />
                    <img id="Image" src="#" style="width: 100px; visibility: hidden;" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script lang="en" type="text/javascript">
        function btnAddPrimaryImage_Click() {
            var template = "<h4 class='PrimaryImageTitle'>Primary Image<a onclick='removePanel(this);' style='float:right'>X</a></h4>\n";
            template += "<div class='AccordionPanel'><div class='row form-group'>\n";
            template += "<label for='ImageSelector' class='control-label col-md-2'>Project Image</label>\n";
            template += "<div class='col-md-10'>\n";
            template += "<input type='file' id='Image1Selector' /><br />\n";
            template += "<img id='Image' src='#' style='width: 100px; visibility: hidden;' />\n";
            template += "</div></div></div>\n";

            $("#PrimaryImageAccordion").append(template);

            $("#PrimaryImageAccordion").accordion("refresh");
        }

        function removePanel(a) {
            $(a).parent().next().remove();
            $(a).parent().remove();
            $("#PrimaryImageAccordion").accordion("refresh");
            return false;
        }

        function ImageSelector_Change(object, input) {
            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    object.attr("src", e.target.result);
                    object.css("visibility", "visible");
                }

                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**Update 1**

Changed my main selector/loader function as follows:

```
function ImageSelector_Change(input) {
    var object = $(input).parent().find('img#Image');

    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            object.attr("src", e.target.result);
            object.css("visibility", "visible");
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```

only problem is that it loads the first image only, not the additional images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IDs must be unique.

So in the function ***btnAddPrimaryImage_Click*** I corrected how the new elements are added to the accordion using an incremental variable.

The  function ***ImageSelector_Change*** needs to get two parameters:

- this: in order to get image
- image id where to put the loaded image.

Moreover, because you are using bootstrap I suggest you to avoid jQuery 3.x for compatibility issues.

The snippet:

```js
$(function () {
  $("#PrimaryImageAccordion").accordion({
    collapsible: true
  });
});

 var idCounter = 0;
    function btnAddPrimaryImage_Click() {
        idCounter++;
        var template = "<h4 class='PrimaryImageTitle'>Primary Image<a onclick='removePanel(this);' style='float:right'>X</a></h4>\n";
        template += "<div class='AccordionPanel'><div class='row form-group'>\n";
        template += "<label for='ImageSelector'" + idCounter + " class='control-label col-md-2'>Project Image</label>\n";
        template += "<div class='col-md-10'>\n";
        template += "<input type='file' id='ImageSelector" + idCounter + "' onchange='ImageSelector_Change(this,\"Image" + idCounter + "\");' /><br />\n";
        template += "<img id='Image" + idCounter + "' src='#' style='width: 100px; visibility: hidden;' />\n";
        template += "</div></div></div>\n";

        $("#PrimaryImageAccordion").append(template);

        $("#PrimaryImageAccordion").accordion("refresh");
    }

    function removePanel(a) {
        $(a).parent().next().remove();
        $(a).parent().remove();
        $("#PrimaryImageAccordion").accordion("refresh");
        return false;
    }

    function ImageSelector_Change(object, input) {
        if (object.files && object.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                document.getElementById(input).src = e.target.result;
                document.getElementById(input).style.visibility = "visible";
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(object.files[0]);
        }
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<br /><br />
<button type='button' onclick='btnAddPrimaryImage_Click();' class='btn btn-default'> Add </button>
<div id="PrimaryImageAccordion">
    <h4 class="PrimaryImageTitle">Primary Image</h4>
    <div>
        <div class="row form-group">
            <label for="ImageSelector" class="control-label col-md-2">Project Image</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="file" id="ImageSelector" onchange="ImageSelector_Change(this, 'Image');" /><br />
                <img id="Image" src="#" style="width: 100px; visibility: hidden;" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: getting `Cannot set property 'src' of null` at line 65. Specifically `document.getElementById(input).src = e.target.result;`. I was able to get it working with my answer, any chance on getting the two answers working together?

Comment: @JohnSchultz I changed the inline event: onchange="ImageSelector_Change(this, 'Image');"  where this is the input type file and the second parameter is the id of the corresponding img tag.  Does it work in my snippet?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to change this function parameters as single like this.
Because  your `onchange` event fires this function with single parameter.
So it will receive the `object` but your trying to access the `input` which has the `undefined` value
Here take one global variable increment because as many times your clicking the button those many times DOM image element having the samaID

```
var vrImgeID=0;
 function btnAddPrimaryImage_Click() {
   var template = "<h4 class='PrimaryImageTitle'>Primary Image<a onclick='removePanel(this);' style='float:right'>X</a></h4>\n";
   template += "<div class='AccordionPanel'><div class='row form-group'>\n";
   template += "<label for='ImageSelector' class='control-label col-md-2'>Project Image</label>\n";
   template += "<div class='col-md-10'>\n";
   template += "<input type='file' id='Image1Selector' /><br />\n";
   template += "<img id='Image"+vrImgeID+"' src='#' style='width: 100px; visibility: hidden;' />\n";
   template += "</div></div></div>\n";

   $("#PrimaryImageAccordion").append(template);
   vrImgeID++;

   $("#PrimaryImageAccordion").accordion("refresh");
 }



function ImageSelector_Change(input) {
            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    input.attr("src", e.target.result);
                    input.css("visibility", "visible");
                }

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this sort of works, had to find the img tag, updated OP.

Comment: I didn't get you what exactly your trying to do

Comment: trying to create a multi-image uploader that previews each image after you select it. each image has to be separated using the accordion as this will be used elsewhere.

Comment: Can you check once my updated code. still you have issue??

Comment: Read my update on the OP, there is a JS code that defines an object, this is what makes it work.

Answer (score 0):

My finished code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- css links -->
    <link href="/Content/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.0/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- /css links -->
    <!-- js files  -->
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <!-- /js files -->
</head>
<body id="myPage" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="60">
    <script lang="en" type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#PrimaryImageAccordion").accordion({
                collapsible: true
            });
        });
    </script>
    <br /><br />
    <button type='button' onclick='btnAddPrimaryImage_Click();' class='btn btn-default'> Add </button>
    <div id="PrimaryImageAccordion">
        <h4 class="PrimaryImageTitle">Primary Image</h4>
        <div>
            <div class="row form-group">
                <label for="ImageSelector" class="control-label col-md-2">Project Image</label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <input type="file" id="ImageSelector" onchange="ImageSelector_Change(this);" /><br />
                    <img id="Image" src="#" style="width: 100px; visibility: hidden;" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script lang="en" type="text/javascript">
        function btnAddPrimaryImage_Click() {
            var template = "<h4 class='PrimaryImageTitle'>Primary Image<a onclick='removePanel(this);' style='float:right'>X</a></h4>\n";
            template += "<div class='AccordionPanel'><div class='row form-group'>\n";
            template += "<label for='ImageSelector' class='control-label col-md-2'>Project Image</label>\n";
            template += "<div class='col-md-10'>\n";
            template += "<input type='file' id='ImageSelector' onchange='ImageSelector_Change(this);' /><br />\n";
            template += "<img id='Image' src='#' style='width: 100px; visibility: hidden;' />\n";
            template += "</div></div></div>\n";

            $("#PrimaryImageAccordion").append(template);

            $("#PrimaryImageAccordion").accordion("refresh");
        }

        function removePanel(a) {
            $(a).parent().next().remove();
            $(a).parent().remove();
            $("#PrimaryImageAccordion").accordion("refresh");
            return false;
        }

        function ImageSelector_Change(input) {
            var object = $(input).parent().find('img#Image');

            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    object.attr("src", e.target.result);
                    object.css("visibility", "visible");
                }

                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Found out the hard way that when you add code to the first object (the accordion panel) you also have to add the same code to the template in order to make the image loader work :p.